# R package build check only outputs pdf of single panel figures

Tags: r, rstudio

I have authored a package and am able to successfully build and check the package using RStudio (w/ devtools and roxygen2). I have several functions where an example plot is a multi-panel plot using the `layout` function. These multi-panle plots are not produced in the examples pdf.

Is there any way to include these in the output?

Comment: Not sure. Have you tried ggplot2 graphics with `gridExtra::grid.arrange`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution - One needs to call `par` to set up the device first, then `layout` to adjust plot facets:

```
# Example plot
op <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
layout(matrix(c(1,3,2,3),nrow=2, ncol=2), widths=c(5,3), heights=c(3,3), respect=TRUE)
par(ps=10, cex=1, mar=c(4,4,1,1))
plot(1)
plot(2)
plot(3)
par(op)
```